# Including post_type = 'wiki' in author archives

Tags: archives, author, wiki, post-type

For a user with wiki-update permission only, I want to list their wiki articles in the author archive page. Currently, it comes back with "NOT FOUND   Apologies, but ...".

I am using the Twenty-ten child theme and created a custom loop-wiki.php but now have a block about how to proceed. Any ideas? Anyone? I've searched and found similar type discussion but nothing stands out.

Thanks!

Comment: [Related question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/137354/include-both-default-and-custom-post-type-in-query-modified-inside-pre-get-posts/137359?noredirect=1#comment195606_137359).

Answer (score 7):

Author archives default to searching for posts of the post type `post`. You could override this with `wiki` like so;

```
function wpse_11210_set_wiki_for_author( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_author() )
        $query->set( 'post_type', 'wiki' );
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse_11210_set_wiki_for_author' );
```

Drop it in your a plugin or your theme's `functions.php` (if the file doesn't exist, create it).

Comment: Hey there TheDeadMedic,

Tried your advice, it worked, all too well! Thank you immensely!

Now, if I can insert a test to discern between wiki-editor vs post author, I'll be "cook'n with gas!"

Thanks again for your expertise!

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean - do you want to check if the author (or the current user) has a certain role or capability?

Comment: I think they want only the query to grab  the original author and not the editors so if I create a wiki article then my author page shows that but if I edit another person wiki article then it does not show in my author page. although I always thought a wiki was public contribution and that no one owns it.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic what do you mean when you say "run once"? In the remove_action( 'pre_get_posts', '__set_wiki_for_author' ); Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: If we didn't remove the action after the first call, it would apply to every successive `WP_Query` call (which would meddle with a theme or plugin's own query). In WordPress 3.3, you can simply use `is_main_query()` to ensure it only runs for the request.