# Include both default and Custom Post Type in query modified inside pre_get_posts

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, query

I want to include custom post type in the author arhive page. I tried the method discussed in this post:

> [Including post_type = 'wiki' in author archives](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11210/including-post-type-wiki-in-author-archives)

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_post_author_archive' );
function custom_post_author_archive( &$query )
{
    if ( $query->is_author )
    {
        $query->set( 'post_type', 'custom_name' );
        remove_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_post_author_archive' ); // run once!
    }
}
```

But by this method, only the custom_name posts are queried. I want to query both the custom_name posts and the normal posts.

What changes will I have to make?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Kaiser mentioned, the `post_type` parameter can accept an array of post types. Updating the function to use `is_main_query()` to limit the filter to only the "main" query, the code would look like:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_post_author_archive' );
function custom_post_author_archive( $query )
{
    if ( is_main_query() && is_author() )
    {
        set_query_var( 'post_type', array('post','custom_post') );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply said, the `$query` argument inside `pre_get_posts` refers to the `WP_Query` class/object as you can see [in core](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/1ff0aebf20dec2a7a5636127e27c9df58a6a084d/wp-includes/query.php#L2186).

```
do_action_ref_array( 'pre_get_posts', array( &$this ) );
```

That means that any callback/action attached to the hook can do exactly the same thing as `new WP_Query( [ etc. ] );` could do. Therefore you can use an **array of post types** as well.

Comment: thanks a lot ... i understand how this works better now...